# iPad keyboard will not dismiss from a Facebook dialog called from a view controller with a model view controller style UIModalPresentationFormSheet

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook, ipad

I have researched and implemented the advice regarding the keyboard dismissing issue from modal view controllers and have the following code in my UINavigationController

```
- (BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal
{
    return NO;
}
```

This works fine except for when I call the following Facebook dialog when the user does not dismiss the keyboard

```
    [FBWebDialogs presentRequestsDialogModallyWithSession:...]
```

I have tried everything I can find on SO to kill the keyboard; I have walked through each view; I have tried model transition to a new view controller and then calling it; but nothing seams to work. It seams as if the Keyboard is no longer attached to a view so there is nothing to dismiss it any more.

I do not have this issue when I call that dialog from other code.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above "fix" does not work if the view controller is presented inside a navigation controller;

You have to create a category with this "fix":

header file - UINavigationControllerResponderFix.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> 
@interface UINavigationController (ResponderFix)

-(BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal;

@end
```

implementation file:

```
#import "UINavigationControllerResponderFix.h"

@implementation UINavigationController (ResponderFix)

-(BOOL)disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal{
    return NO;
}

@end
```

Now, modify your [applicationname]-Prefix.pch

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

    #import "UINavigationControllerResponderFix.h"
#endif
```

That's it!

This does is make an adjustment for every instance of UINavigationController

All above - taken from here: http://www.danielhanly.com/blog/tutorial/resignfirstresponder-bug-in-uimodalpresentationformsheet/

Comment: that fixed it. I had subclassed the UINavigationController and that is where I added the disablesAutomaticKeyboardDismissal  code. That worked for most cases except for the Facebook dialog